# Python: efficient way to find orthogonal vectors connecting many points (x,y) to the closest spot on a known function y(x)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, minimization, orthogonal

I have a data set comprising a long array of x-values and an equally long array of y-values. For each (x,y) pair, I want to find the nearest points on a known function y(x).

I could in principle loop over each pair and perform a minimization such as scipy.optimize.cobyla, but looping in python is slow.  Scipy's odr package looks interesting, but I can't figure out how to make it simply return the orthogonal vectors without also minimizing the whole thing (setting the maximum iterations "maxit" to zero doesn't give me what I want).

Is there a simple way to get this done using the speed of numpy arrays?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple:

1. Don't loop over points in the list
2. Loop over points on your
   function curve.

I take the liberty to rename your function y(x) into f(z) to avoid confusion.

```
import numpy as np

# x and y are your numpy arrays of point coords
x = np.array([1,2])
y = np.array([3,4])
# this is your "y(x)" function
def f(z):
    return z**2

xmin = x.min()
xmax = x.max()
step = 0.01 # choose your step at the precision you want

# find distances to every point
zpoints = np.arange(xmin,xmax,step)
distances_squared = np.array([(y-f(z))**2+(x-z)**2 for z in zpoints])

# find z coords of closest points
zmin = zpoints[distances_squared.argmin(axis=0)]
fmin = np.array([f(z) for z in zmin])

for i in range(len(x)):
    print("point on the curve {},{} is closest to {},{}".format(zmin[i],fmin[i],x[i],y[i]))
```

> point on the curve 1.6700000000000006,2.788900000000002 is closest to 1,3
>
> point on the curve 1.9900000000000009,3.9601000000000033 is closest to 2,4

Comment: Thanks for your response! It is an interesting idea, to just brute force the search with numpy. If I understand correctly, it will scale in time and memory like (number of data points) x (number of function points), which might get large (I have many more function curve points than data points). I'm guessing this could be sped up by by automating a slice on zpoints to only compare with the relevant points on the function curve. I'll play with this and see if it outdoes the scipy constrained minimizer.

Comment: @Jack, premature optimization is the root of all evil. Just run the code, and see if you care about potential speed difference.

Comment: Heh, thanks. I'm making a general-purpose library, not solving a single problem. I'll put a little thought into it (partly because it's fun to do so).

Comment: Well, the point about optimization still holds - until you do profiling on some "realistic" data and identify the bottleneck there's little point in discussing strategies for speedup. The cost of function evaluation is the primary concern here. In any case you can't get much faster than my approach without regularity assumptions on the curve (differentiability at least) which you probably have. In this case gradient-based optimizers could come in handy.

Comment: There is actually a way to get a big boost (at the expense of RAM), by using numpy loops (written in C) instead of python loops (slow), based on this bare-fist approach. I'll post it in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to speed up Hennadii Madan's approach, by asking numpy to do the looping instead of python. As usual, this comes at the expense of additional RAM.

Below is the function I am now using for 2d. A nice feature is it's symmetric -- one can swap the data sets and the computation time will be the same.

```
def find_nearests_2d(x1, y1, x2, y2):
   """
   Given two data sets d1 = (x1, y1) and d2 = (x2, y2), return the x,y pairs
   from d2 that are closest to each pair from x1, the difference vectors, and
   the d2 indices of these closest points. 

   Parameters
   ----------
   x1
       1D array of x-values for data set 1.
   y1  
       1D array of y-values for data set 1 (must match size of x1).
   x2
       1D array of x-values for data set 2.
   y2
       1D array of y-values for data set 2 (must match size of x2).

   Returns x2mins, y2mins, xdiffs, ydiffs, indices
   -------
   x2mins
       1D array of minimum-distance x-values from data set 2. One value for each x1.
   y2mins
       1D array of minimum-distance y-values from data set 2. One value for each y1.
   xdiffs 
       1D array of differences in x. One value for each x1.
   ydiffs
       1D array of differences in y. One value for each y1.
   indices
       Indices of each minimum-distance point in data set 2. One for each point in
       data set 1.
   """

   # Generate every combination of points for subtracting
   x1s, x2s = _n.meshgrid(x1, x2)
   y1s, y2s = _n.meshgrid(y1, y2)

   # Calculate all the differences
   dx = x1s - x2s
   dy = y1s - y2s
   d2 = dx**2 + dy**2

   # Find the index of the minimum for each data point
   n = _n.argmin(d2, 0)

   # Index for extracting from the meshgrids
   m = range(len(n))

   return x2s[n,m], y2s[n,m], dx[n,m], dy[n,m], d2[n,m], n
```

One can also then use this to quickly estimate the distance between x,y pairs and a function:

```
def find_nearests_function(x, y, f, *args, fpoints=1000):
    """
    Takes a data set (arrays of x and y values), and a function f(x, *args),
    then estimates the points on the curve f(x) that are closest to each of 
    the data set's x,y pairs.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x
        1D array of x-values for data set 1.
    y  
        1D array of y-values for data set 1 (must match size of x).
    f
        A function of the form f(x, *args) with optional additional arguments.
    *args
        Optional additional arguments to send to f (after argument x).
    fpoints=1000
        Number of evenly-spaced points to search in the x-domain (automatically
        the maximum possible range).

    """

    # Make sure everything is a numpy array
    x = _n.array(x)
    y = _n.array(y)

    # First figure out the range we need for f. Since the function is single-
    # valued, we can put bounds on the x-range: for each point, calculate the 
    # y-distance, and subtract / add this to the x-values
    dys  = _n.abs(f(x)-y)
    xmin = min(x-dys)
    xmax = max(x+dys)

    # Get "dense" function arrays
    xf = _n.linspace(xmin, xmax, fpoints)
    yf = f(xf,*args)

    # Find all the minima
    xfs, yfs, dxs, dys, d2s, n = find_nearests_2d(x, y, xf, yf)

    # Return this info plus the function arrays used
    return xfs, yfs, dxs, dys, d2s, n, xf, yf
```

If this is part of an orthogonal distance regression (like in my case), the differences dx and dy can be readily scaled by error bar data sets without much overhead, such that the returned distances are studentized (unitless) residuals.

Ultimately, this "search everywhere uniformly" technique will only get you close, and will fail if the function isn't particularly smooth over the range of x data.

Quick test code:

```
x  = [1,2,5]
y  = [1,-1,1]

def f(x): return _n.cos(x)

fxmin, fymin, dxmin, dymin, d2min, n, xf, yf = find_nearests_function(x, y, f)

import pylab
pylab.plot(x,y, marker='o', ls='', color='m', label='input points')
pylab.plot(xf,yf, color='b', label='function')
pylab.plot(fxmin,fymin, marker='o', ls='', color='r', label='nearest points')
pylab.legend()
pylab.show()
```

produces

[image]